# How to increase the number of characters in a putty session

Tags: unix, putty

I am using Putty to execute some command. The command length that I have is having 323 characters. But its allowing me to type only 256 characters. Please help me. How to increase that limit.

Thanks

Comment: You would be best of going to Super User for this. Try the site for putty as well. It could be a setting on the computer you are connecting to that has imposed this limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for this. I just typed `bash` first and then I tried running the command. It worked successfully.

Answer (score 3):

In case bash is not allowed. you can put you command in a script and run that script. do not forget to make the script executable first.